# Jquery mmenu goes out from a bootstrap 4 layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, mmenu

If i zoom in on my page, or i view it in `responsinator.com`, sometimes, or in landscape view, the menu wont collapse in to the mobile version.

I am using the [jquery mmenu plugin](https://mmenujs.com/documentation/wrappers/bootstrap.html), and **bootstrap 4** justified `nav`.

I tryed removing the justified class, but it still has the same problem, and also, i need the justified menu. For the menu, i **don't** have any custom css, just colors, font-size...

[You can take a look at my page here.](https://kemenyem.hu/informaciok)

```
<div class="site_navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars navbar_ikon"></i>
                </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-justified w-100 container mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="/kategoria/1/barabas-terko" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Barabás térkő</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/6/barabas-terko/barabas-badacsony-terko">Barabás Badacsony térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/7/barabas-terko/barabas-gerecse-terko">Barabás Gerecse térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/5/barabas-terko/barabas-somlo-trio-terko">Barabás Somló Trió térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/8/barabas-terko/barabas-teglako">Barabás Téglakő</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/kategoria/36/kerti-szegely" class="nav-link">Kerti szegély</a></li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="/kategoria/10/terko-meret-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő méret szerint</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/15/terko-meret-szerint/10x20-cm-terko">10x20 cm térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/18/terko-meret-szerint/20x13-3-cm-terko">20x13,3 cm térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/19/terko-meret-szerint/vegyes-meretu-kombi-terko">Vegyes méretű, kombi térkő</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="/kategoria/9/terko-vastagsag-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő vastagság szerint</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/11/terko-vastagsag-szerint/4-cm-vastag-terko">4 cm vastag térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/12/terko-vastagsag-szerint/5-cm-vastag-terko">5 cm vastag térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/13/terko-vastagsag-szerint/6-cm-vastag-terko">6 cm vastag térkő</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/kategoria/14/terko-vastagsag-szerint/8-cm-vastag-terko">8 cm vastag térkő</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i view the page on tablet or mobile, i **don't** want to see to menu, only just the menu `toggler-icon`.

Comment: Hi Max, I checked the url from my mobile and the menu seems to work well. Is it already Fixed?

Comment: Hello! No, i didnt do anything. If you check it on the responsinator site, you will see the bugs.

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, on any resolution lower than 578px, the navigation will be converted via a burger menu... but since you want the complete navigation to dissappear on a tablet... you would have to change the class from `<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">` into from `<div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">`

**working snippet** with navigation currently and what you need it to be:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Current Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navigation which you need below</h3>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar you want</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello! I changed the class, but nothing happend. I dont have no idea, whats going on. I checked it on the responsinator.com, and i resized my window, but still the same problem.

Comment: Where did you check? On the link that you gave? Was the code changed from `sm` to `md` when you did inspect element? You might have gotten cached results